# "Go to matching brace" in TextMate 1.5

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to go to a matching brace in TextMate 1.5?

I can't just collapse the block because it's a badly formatted file, **but** the matching brace might be successfully recognized anyway. I just need to go to it (since it's distant more than 1-screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TextMate 1.x you can select the contents of the surrounding braces using <kbd>⇧⌘B</kbd>. After this you can use the arrow keys to go the start/end of the selection. You could record a macro to make this a single action.

In TextMate 2 going to matching brace can be done with <kbd>⌃↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌃↓</kbd>. These keys can also be used with shift (<kbd>⇧</kbd>) to select to matching brace.

Comment: Allan, unfortunately on recent OS X versions the bindings for TM2 are reserved on the OS level, for Mission Control and Application Windows. Is it possible to make a "Find matching brace" shortcut that will essentially jump to the highlited match? It would be extremely useful e.g. when editing JavaScript callback hell.

Comment: Is there anything that can be combined with the mouse? For example in Xcode, double-clicking a brace will select to the matching brace, which is extremely convenient.

Comment: You can turn off the Mission Control/App window bindings to get this insanely helpful feature to work. Go to `System Prefs > Mission Control` and toggle off the `⌃↑` and `⌃↓`. Almost lost me to Sublime Text! @MaratC