# How to jump to a matching brace in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Is there a workaround for the problem with textmate's Jump to matching brace issue? Is there anyway to disable the OS level   ⌃↑ and ⌃↓  ? Or to customize textmates key bindings?

Somehow relevant, but not satisfactory answers:
["Go to matching brace" in TextMate 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142680/go-to-matching-brace-in-textmate-1-5/24587345#24587345)

[Setting Shortcut Keys in Textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417406/setting-shortcut-keys-in-textmate?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

For Textmate 2 the key bindings that @[Allan Odgaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712044/allan-odgaard) posted [in a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587345/2919380) are perfect:

> In TextMate 2 going to matching brace can be done with <kbd>⌃↑</kbd>
>   and <kbd>⌃↓</kbd>. These keys can also be used with shift
>   (<kbd>⇧</kbd>) to select to matching brace.

yet [@MaratC is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142680/go-to-matching-brace-in-textmate-1-5/32451878?noredirect=1#comment45644032_24587345) - they are bound to system wide Mission Control functions.

These can be changed in: 
System Preferences... Keyboard... Shortcuts pane/tab:
   in the Mission Control Section. 
After choosing alternative shortcuts for mission control, go to AppleMenu... Force Quit.. Relaunch Finder and the shortcut keys will be available in TextMate.